# Proper way for user authentication with angularjs and flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, authentication, flask-security

I'm currently working my way through Web development with flask. I want to build a webapp with flask as backend and angular.js at the frontend. The Json part is straight forward, and my first steps work out well. But now I got stuck with User Authentication. I read a lot but found out, that WTFForms works not as well with angular (without the CSFR Token), so i can not use something like flask-security.

What is a proper way or maybe the *best pratice* for implementing User authentication with Angular und Flask? (Maybe someone knows a good example app I can learn from by example)

Comment: Take a look in this repository. https://github.com/weinbergdavid/python-flask-security

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have written several tutorials on RESTful APIs with Flask, all with examples that are ready to use:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/category/REST

The tutorials are:

- [Designing a RESTful API with Python and Flask](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask)

  This is a simple RESTful API written in Flask, with authentication.
- [Writing a Javascript REST client](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/writing-a-javascript-rest-client)

  In this one I implement a Javascript client for the API built in the first tutorial. Here you can see how the client authenticates. I used Knockout instead of Angular for the client, but the principles are the same.
- [Designing a RESTful API using Flask-RESTful](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-using-flask-restful)

  This one is another way to write the server, using the Flask-RESTful extension to simplify some tasks.
- [RESTful Authentication with Flask](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask)

  This is a tutorial specifically dedicated to authentication.

I hope they are useful.

Comment: +1 to Miguel and his blog, thanks for the huge effort you put in on Flask knowledge sharing.

Comment: I'll go with token based auth - Miguel did great job on his blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask-security together with Angular. You can even get CSRF support. I simply disabled WTFForms support and used the Flask backend only as REST API.
I wrote a tutorial how to do this [here](https://www.xemedo.com/en/single-page-applications-with-flask-and-angular/). Source code is also available.