# Flask API to provide JSON files to a simple HTML+JS+CSS webapp while keeping it secure

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-restful

I've made a simple webapp that is going to show some data in a table, which will be updated weekly.

This update it done in the backend with some python code, that scrapes and alters some data, before putting it in a SQLite database.

After doing some reading I learned that to deliver that data to my webapp I should make a API with Flask, that can take that data and deliver it to the JS in my webapp in form of JSON, which then can use the data to populate the table. However, I should secure my API with username and pw. But as its a JS frontend that will retrieve data from the API, there is really no point, as the username and pw will have to be hardcoded into JS, which then can be read by the users. (I think)

Should I expose my API to everyone, or is this not the way to go to be able to use SQLite data as a backend for my webapp? I am fine keeping the API to a GET only.

Comment: Will your users be authenticated to the website when they access it or is it something like google where anyone can go to the site? Personally I would never expose an api without some form of authentication.

Comment: [This answer by Miguel seems to answer your questions in depth.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635756/7838574) I highly recommend the author he is well versed in flask.

Comment: @DanielButler Thank you for your two comments. The site I have in mind is a table that shows an aggregate of some already public data. I will read you link, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it is pointless for you to secure your API.  Securing an API is only needed in certain circumstances.

If you are accessing data that you don't want anybody to see, perhaps through a backend call, then it would make sense to add in some form of security (normally an API key or Authorisation tokens in your request headers).

However, if you are making calls from your front-end (i.e. client side) to a backend API, then there is no point putting additional security there as the user can already see the request and already has access to the data the API is returning - so by securing it you are achieving nothing.

Normally, if the page the user is visiting contains sensitive data that you don't want everyone to see, you would take steps to secure your website instead (for example protecting it with a login for username and password before you can access that page).  If you were to take this approach, where the website is protected by username and password, then you can update the API to make sure it does not respond to requests where the user is not authenticated (e.g. by generating a session token or something unique for each logged in user).

If you have a look around on websites that have lots of free data available, you will find they all have front end API calls that are completely unsecured (because it is pointless if the data is already free to access).  Some websites do take steps to try to make sure it is their own website that is calling the API, but even then it is a bit pointless as web **scrapers** can always extract the data from the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/06/01/add-a-authentication-header-to-your-python-flask-app/) which outlines authentication headers. This simpler route is to hard code the header info in Flask to make it a little more secure. You could also try the more involved route of reading header info from your db. What's currently working for me to read from postgres db is below so you may modify it slightly for sqlite.

```
def valid():
  headers = request.headers
  auth = headers.get("X-Api-Key")
  user = User.query.filter_by(apikey=auth).first_or_404()
  print('from search of db ',user,'',auth)
  return str(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As you mentioned, you plan to show a public data - then it can be used even
   without authentication. Otherwise I think it can take too much unnecessary time spent on that.
2. As you have just a simple and single table from database, I believe that you don't need an API. You can just create HTML template and render it with data. Some [examples can be found here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/) and [few more here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates).